# Code brevity in C# - condensing a setter that throws if null

Tags: c#, getter-setter, setter

In prior versions of C#, if you wanted to prevent a null reference exception, you needed to build your setters defensively:

```
public Guid ItemId { get; set; } //foreign key, required

private Item _item;
public virtual Item Item {
  get {
    return _item;
  }
  set {
    if(value == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(value));
    _item = value;
    ItemId = value.ItemId;
  }
}
```

With more modern implementations, this can be condensed a certain amount using the null-coalescing operator and expression bodies:

```
private Item _item;
public virtual Item Item {
  get => _item;
  set => _item = value ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(value));
}
```

However, I am curious if this could not be condensed entirely down into a variation of the standard reference:

```
public virtual Item Item { get; set; }
```

Such that you do not have to define a private item.

Suggestions? Or is the second code block as efficient/simple as I can get?

I am looking for a solution within the current C# framework, not something I have to spend money on. Right now my use case proposition does not support a paid product

Comment: Look into aspect-oriented programming, PostSharp.

Comment: I am actually looking for a solution within the current C# framework, not something I have to spend money on. Right now my use case proposition does not support a paid product.

Comment: “Code brevity in C#”

Comment: "In your question". I went ahead and put the additional info from your comment, which affects the validity of potential answers, right in your question. You can do so yourself next time by clicking [edit], you also may want to read [ask].

Comment: Perhaps it is just me, but I have always considered the title to be an integral part of the whole post, and a part of the question itself. Unless titles are really isolated from the content, and have no relationship to it? That would be critically problematic from a significant number of positions.

Comment: You seem to be linguistically capable enough to realise that "code brevity in C#" doesn't quite have the same ring to it as "I don't want to use third-party libraries, especially not if they cost money", right?

Answer (score 1):

**Disclaimer**: Those are potential 'alternative' ways of filtering out invalid assignments into properties. This might not provide a straight answer to the question, but rather give ideas how to go on about doing it more generically without defining private properties and defining `getters` and `setters` explicitly.

Depending on what `Item` actually is, you could perhaps create a `non-nullable` type of `Item` by creating it as a struct.

Non nullable types are called `structs`. They are nothing new, they are value types which allow to store properties of type int, string, bool etc.

As on MSDN:

> A struct type is a value type that is typically used to encapsulate
>   small groups of related variables, such as the coordinates of a
>   rectangle or the characteristics of an item in an inventory.
>
> The following example shows a simple struct declaration:

```
public struct Book  
{  
    public decimal price{ get; set;}
    public string title;  
    public string author;  
}
```

[Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/struct)

Edit (`Struct` should be sufficient if the `object` is supposed to be `non-nullable type`, however if we're talking properties of the class then read below.) :

Another way would be using `OnPropertyChanged` event which is part of the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface.

While the event does not explicitly give you the value that has been changed to, you can grab it as it does provide you the property name. So you could run your validation post assignment and throw then, I suppose however it might not be the best option.

```
void item_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var propertyValue = sender.GetType().GetProperty(e.PropertyName).GetValue(sender);
}
```

Another solution would be using `DataAnnotations` and add `Required` attributes on your properties. If I'm not mistaken they will not throw straight away, until you call your own validate function to validate the class, I guess, combined with the above method this would work pretty well and would be pretty generic. Once written you wouldn't have to write your `getters` and `setters` explicitly but rather attach just one event to your class and validate it once a property changes.

Here's a small example:

Your `Item` model for example...

```
public class Item
{
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; } 
}
```

You would then implement a generic function which would validate all properties.

```
public bool TryValidate(object @object, out ICollection < ValidationResult > results) {
   var context = new ValidationContext(@object, serviceProvider: null, items: null);

   results = new List <ValidationResult> ();

   return Validator.TryValidateObject(
    @object, context, results,
    validateAllProperties: true
   );
}
```

Inside that function you would of course throw an exception if validation failed, your `results` array would contain properties that it failed on an default messages if I'm not mistaken. I believe this is a bit complex, but if you're looking for reducing the number of properties and `setter` implementations, this could be a step forward. I'm not sure on the overhead etc. Personally, I think on a larger scale, this would be super useful to validate models which are created on the fly from db data or any external source.

[Validator Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.validator.aspx) | [Data Annotations Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations(v=vs.110).aspx) | [ValidationResults Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.validationresult(v=vs.110).aspx) | [PropertyChanged MSDN Sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/how-to-implement-property-change-notification)

Comment: Edited for example of get/set in struct

Comment: I should have probably been a little more explicit, but my intent was to make this as generic as possible so as to not get other concerns entangled. This is for simple MVC 5, repository pattern, DDD, working with the domain entities. Not sure how a struct can help there (never worked with structs before), as I am “working with” tables and fields in a database under code-first principles.

Comment: @RenéKåbis I don't see how a struct makes it less generic than a standard class object in your case and stops anything you said above. If `Item` is not to be null, making it `non-nullable type (struct)` would be sufficient. If you're talking specific properties inside of `Item` then read my edit.